# react axios - losing this context despite using arrow functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, axios, arrow-functions

I have in my component this function to post data. This works fine, but on the success message, the `this` context of my component is lost. Why? I'm using arrow functions. Why is the `this` context being lost this way? 
The problem is to call the function `this.props.onUpdate();` if the post is successful.

```
handlePriceUpdateClickConfirm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios.post('../data/post/json/massUpdatePrices', {
        _token : window.Laravel.csrfToken,
        percent: this.refs.percent.value,
        IDs: this.props.selectedFreights,
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        if(response.data != undefined && response.data != null && response.data.success == true) {
            this.props.onUpdate();
        }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the main function, `handlePriceUpdateClickConfirm`, is not bound to the class itself since it is not an arrow function (nor bound, I imagine), and all functions get the same context as this one.

You could solve it by changing your function declaration to the following. I would also recommand deconstructing your props to keep your variables declared in your function's scope :

```
handlePriceUpdateClickConfirm = event => {
    const { onUpdate } = this.props
    /* */
    if(response.data && response.data && response.data.success) {
        onUpdate();
    }
}
```