# Axios + React (Next.js), post request loses track of the context / state

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios

Been scratching my head for hours, this bug doesn't make any sense to me.

Similarly to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54665427/react-axios-losing-this-context-despite-using-arrow-functions) solved problem, the react context and state is lost after the request is complete. The only problem is that all my functions are already bound.

The code below should return an image url and add it to the "image" array state every time the button is clicked.
What's not working is that the contents of the "image" array state is magically forgotten inside the axios promise, meaning that all previous images are lost, and only the image returned by the request will end up in the state.

I never had something like this happen before, feel like i must be missing some incredibly stupid mistake i've made. Anyone have any ideas what might be going on here?

Thank you,

```
// Added
const RANDOM_PROMPTS = [
    'a whale flying in the sky',
    'a skeleton dancing',
    'a sunflower growing in a field'
]

export default function Home() {

    const [prompt, setPrompt] = useState('')
    const [images, setImages] = useState([])

    // Added
    useEffect(() => {
        randomPrompt()
    }, []) 

    const handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()

        axios.post('http://localhost:3000/v1/generate', {prompt})
        .then(res => {
            res.data && add(res.data.url)
        })
    }

    const add = (url) => {
        // images state is always [] here
        console.log(images)
        setImages([...images, url])
    }
    
    // Added
    const randomPrompt = () => {
        const prompt = RANDOM_PROMPTS.shift()
        
        setPrompt(`a painting of ${prompt}, by Paul Delvaux`)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" value={prompt} onChange={event => setPrompt(event.target.value)}/>
                <button type="submit">Draw</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Did you try to initiate Axios request in a different function which executes with a useEffect() hook? (I mean the handleSubmit can change a variable which will be the dependency for useEffect)

Comment: I did have a useEffect hook, but it was to my understanding not connected to, or was initiating the axios request in any way. That said when i removed it, it started working as expected. 

The useEffect was used to randomize the prompt on mount, i have edited the question and added it to the code. If you understand how this could break the axios request, i would love to hear what you think.

Comment: And thank you so much for helping me fix it. Also, should i now be worried about useEffect hooks breaking axios from a completely different part of the application?

Comment: I think KALrious pointed a good point. I edited my answer to include useEffect with async function calling. His answer should fix the issue as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to make youre function handleSubmit async function ?

```js
 const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()

        const {data} = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/v1/generate', 
        {prompt},{
         validateStatus: (status) => status === 201,
        })
        if(!!data && !!data.url) {
          add(data.url)
        }
    }
```

Je rajouterais que tu peux modifier ta fonction add comme suit:

```js
const add = (url) => {
        console.log(images)
        setImages((prevState) => [...prevState, url])
    }
```

My opinion is during the .then you may lose the contexte of youre react state.

Comment: Async + await handleSumbit made no difference, but "setImages((prevState) => [...prevState, url])" works! Wow i had no idea i could use prevState like that in a setState hook, and i've been doing react for years lol. The more you know. Thank you KALrious. Still pretty confusing to me how the context is just lost, but happy that you found a solution.

Comment: Please to help you a bit ;)

Answer (score 0):

Random Prompts should not have any effect on the Axios request you are making on a different useEffect() dependency. Please try my code below which I tried to do what I suggested in my comment.

```
const RANDOM_PROMPTS = [
    'a whale flying in the sky',
    'a skeleton dancing',
    'a sunflower growing in a field'
]

export default function Home() {

    const [prompt, setPrompt] = useState('')
    const [images, setImages] = useState([])
    const [initiateRequest, setInitiateRequest] = useState(false)

    // Added
    useEffect(() => {
        randomPrompt()
    }, []) 

async function fetchData() {
    let response = axios.post('http://localhost:3000/v1/generate', {prompt})
        .then(res => {
            res.data && add(res.data.url)
        })
  }
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData()
    }, [initiateRequest]) 

    const handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
        setInitiateRequest(true)
    }

    const add = (url) => {
        // images state is always [] here
        console.log(images)
        setImages([...images, url])
    }
    
    // Added
    const randomPrompt = () => {
        const prompt = RANDOM_PROMPTS.shift()
        
        setPrompt(`a painting of ${prompt}, by Paul Delvaux`)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" value={prompt} onChange={event => setPrompt(event.target.value)}/>
                <button type="submit">Draw</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: It's so strange, async didn't make any difference. It should have been the first thing i tried though, i pretty much never use .then(). KALrious answer taught me that i can use prevState in a transformer when setting state, i had no idea that was possible. This seems like the cleanest solution. Though i'm still somewhat confused how the context is simply lost, but happy that there's a neat solution. Thank you for helping, Ozgur Sar